# Multiply and shift array elements

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I have been at this algorithm for some time but I just can not get it. Here is what needs to happen:

I have an array 1 (row does not shift):  `.10 .15 .20 .30`

and an array 2 (will shift left): `.25 .30 .28 .11`

The algorithm I need is below.

```
.10 .15 .20 .30
.25 .30 .28 .11

multiply .10 * .25
multiply .15 * .30
multiply .20 * .28
multiply .30 * .11
```

Then:

- Sum the total of these multiplications
- Shift the bottom array index 1 to the left and tack the element in index 1 onto the back of the array so now the multiplication would be

  ```
  .10 .15 .20 .30
  .30 .28 .11 .25
  ```
- Repeat multiplication
- Repeat sum of these multiplications

This would continue until we cycled through all the way through once.

**My attempt:**

```
float[] statProp = {.25 .30 .28 .11};
float[] statProperties = {.10 .15 .20 .30}
float statPropTotal=0;
for(int z=0; z<5; z++){
    for(int x =0; x < 5)
    statProp[z] = stat[z+1] * (float)statProperties[z];
}
for(int z=0; z<5; z++){
     float statPropTotal=0;
     statPropTotal += (float)statProp[x];
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you still show us what you tried.

Comment: I can do that..give me a second

Comment: updated  @Maljam. Be forewarned its terrible lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I get it (some fixes for performance):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] arr1 = {.10, .15, .20, .30};
    double[] arr2 = {.25, .30, .28, .11};

    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < arr1.length) {
        int j = count;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++, j++) {
            if (j > arr1.length - 1) {
                j = 0;
            }
            sum += arr1[i] * arr2[j];
        }
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: pls pay attention to my performance-related fixes of original method. System.arraycopy is expensive and luckily we can use complex index instead in this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode to hint you towards a working algorithm (let us have `float[] a1` and `float[] a2`):

Before getting in the code, let us imagine that instead of changing the index of the values in `a2`, we are just sliding the arrays against each other:

```
.10 .15 .20 .30
        .25 .30 .28 .11
__2__↑   ↑-1-↑   ↑__2__
```

So we can calculate the multiplication/sum with two loops for part `1` and `2`

```
double sum = 0;

//main loop, where i represents by how much you are shifting a2
for(int i = 0 ; i < a2.length ; i++) {

    //loop for part #1
    for(int j = i ; j < a2.length ; j++) {
        sum = sum + (a1[?] * a2[j]);
    }

    //loop for part #2
    for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++) {
        sum = sum + (a1[j] * a2[?]);
    }
}
```

Here, I left some of the logic for you to figure out, but everything is there